# parallel lines and a plane

Tags: plane-geometry

Explain why two parallel lines define a plane.

If I hold two pencils so that they’re parallel, there’s only one position in which a plane can rest on both pencils.But can someone give me a more valid reason? Should I use definition of a plane?

Comment: Because three points define a [plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(geometry)#Planes_embedded_in_three-dimensional_Euclidean_space).

Comment: 2 parallel lines in a *flat* space define a plane. On a curved manifold they don't - e.g. lines of longitude.

Comment: Right, by definition of a plane that is true. But the explanation can't be that simple, right? If we are talking about parallel lines, how do they define a plane? How do we know they lie on the same plane?

Comment: @Donna They do since being parallel requires the lines to be co-planar.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate all the help you have all given me :)

Comment: @PaulChilds it is often helpful to look at the tags before commenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to expand on the comments a little.

Three points indeed define a plane, but if you have two lines, $L1$ and $L2$ you have lots of choices for those three points. Pick any two points on $L1$ to start, and then we need to pick one point on $L2$ to define our plane. If the lines are *not* parallel, then your choice matters a lot! But if the lines *are* parallel, then it doesn't matter which point you pick on $L2$ -- every choice gives the same plane.